# "A 1000 accounts" or "1000 accounts"

Tags: differences

A friend tweeted

> I am following a 1000 accounts now

and I told him it was wrong but he says it's correct. I'm of the view that the correct one is

> I am following 1000 accounts now.

So which one is correct?

Comment: This is Not A Real Question. In speech, or using orthography to represent speech accurately, one would **say** *"...following a thousand accounts"*. If there's a "real" question here, it's simply *"Does '100' represent '**a** hundred', or just the word 'hundred'?"*. But that would be a pointless question anyway, imho.

Comment: FumbleFingers does have a valid point here. You would really only write "a thousand" explicitly, and never "a 1000" as a matter of course. Whether or not you say "a thousand" when you come across 1000 in-text is beside the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what you're experiencing.

These days, in the rush of social selling/ content marketing, it has become very common to see ads like: "Connect with 1000s of leading business experts."

Personally, I find it distracting to read because technically it should be read as "Connect with ONE THOUSANDS of..."

But what how the ads want you to read it is: "Connect with THOUSANDS of..." only.

I attribute it to the marketers' desire to maximize space and abbreviate in widgets, Tweets, etc.

So, in the end, personally I'd say "a 1000" is redundant and I wouldn't be caught using that. But then, in this age of Tweets, who's to prescribe what's better?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:
a thousand -> 1000
two thousand -> 2000

in "a thousand", "a" comes in place of "1". You could say it "one thousand" as well.

Saying "a 1000" is a little bit redundant. I'm not sure if it is 'forbidden', though.